# How to create Super admin in the new firebase/firestore app after deploy ot production?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

My app (not in production yet) has few types of accounts like a typical user, admin, and super admin. The difference between super admin and admin is that only super admin can create usual admin accounts (with httpcallable function and using setCustomUserClaims).

If I decide to deploy my app to a production environment, I need to have an empty firestore DB with one super admin account. Of course, I can add a new account in firebase console, but I don't know how to create that account with setCustomUserClaims. I don't know how to do it properly, because deploy firebase function with something like

```
export const userOnCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user, context) => {
  // some code

  if (user.email === 'xxx@example.com') {
   admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { role: 'super_admin' });
  }
});
```

and delete that code after creating super_admin account is a bad idea.. ;)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure ;) It just sounds like 'there should be a better option' from secure or good practices point of view. Isn't it? (edited, somebody removed his comment)

Comment: Why do you think it is a bad idea to deploy this Cloud Function, run it once and delete (by redeploying your Cloud Functions)? If this claim has to be assigned only once, this is a totally valid approach IMHO. You my have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which explains how to create an Admin module for managing users access and roles. At the end of the article I explain how to use a similar approach to assign super admin claims.

Comment: "edited, somebody removed his comment" -> I actually removed my comment by error... The one above is exactly similar to the comment you answered to ;-)

Comment: Great, thank you Renaud :)